# Copying Qt DLLs to executable directory on Windows using CMake

Tags: windows, cmake, qt5

New to CMake, and I'm having a hard time understanding how to use generator expressions. I'm trying to use `add_custom_command` to create a post-build command to copy Qt DLLs to the executable directory.

In `Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake` I can see it creates different properties for the Qt5::Widgets target to refer to the DLL, depending on the currently active configuration. Either `IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG` or `IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE`. I expected to be able to use the `$<CONFIG:Debug>` generator expression as a condition in an `if()` but that doesn't work.

My CMakeLists.txt:

```
# minimum version required for proper support of C++11 features in Qt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.0)

set(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES Debug;Release)

# project name and version
project(TPBMon VERSION 0.0.0.1)

# Qt5 libs
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)

# run Qt's MOC when needed
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

add_executable(
    tpbmon
    src/main.cpp
    src/mainwindow.hpp
    src/mainwindow.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(tpbmon Qt5::Widgets)
set_target_properties(
    tpbmon
    PROPERTIES
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin
)
if(WIN32)
    if($<CONFIG:Debug>)
        get_target_property(WIDGETDLL Qt5::Widgets IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG)
    else($<CONFIG:Debug>)
        get_target_property(WIDGETDLL Qt5::Widgets IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE)
    endif($<CONFIG:Debug>)
    add_custom_command(
        TARGET tpbmon POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${WIDGETDLL} $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:tpbmon>
    )
endif(WIN32)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Figured it out myself by modifying the `add_custom_command` call to

```
add_custom_command(
    TARGET tpbmon POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
        $<TARGET_FILE:Qt5::Widgets>
        $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:tpbmon>
)
```

It's amazing what a fresh perspective after a good night's sleep can do. ;)

Comment: Good answer; however `Widgets` depend on `Gui`, and `Core`, and `qwindows.dll` etc. which you should manually append. **`windeployqt`** handles all these dependencies.

Comment: This script doesn't work for me. Visual Studio complains error evaluating expression: Target "Qt6::Widgets" is not an executable or library.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `windeployqt` program which is part of Qt binary release. It will scan your binary and collect all used Qt DLLs, plugins and QML modules. It could be wrapped in CMake as a post-build event by `add_custom_command(TARGET target_name POST_BUILD ...)` signature.

Comment: This is the right answer. windeployqt is a simple and effective tool built by Qt for Qt. Here's a [tutorial](youtube.com/watch?v=8qozxqSZQEg)

Comment: Example usage: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60856725

Answer (score 3):

For the future you can add all Qt5 dependencies to your executable folder:

```
 find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Gui Widgets)
 ...   
 add_custom_command(TARGET MyQtProj POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different $<TARGET_FILE:Qt5::Core> $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:MyQtProj>
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different $<TARGET_FILE:Qt5::Gui> $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:MyQtProj>
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different $<TARGET_FILE:Qt5::Widgets> $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:MyQtProj>
        )
```